# Background GC : Troelsen

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, clr

I've just readed a topic in the internet and I'm confused a bit.

So "Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework" - Andrew Troelsen. Quote:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***** Fun with System.GC *****");
        // Print out estimated number of bytes on heap.
        Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}",
        GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        // MaxGeneration is zero based.
        Console.WriteLine("This OS has {0} object generations.\n",
        (GC.MaxGeneration + 1));
        Car refToMyCar = new Car("Zippy", 100);
        Console.WriteLine(refToMyCar.ToString());
        // Print out generation of refToMyCar.
        Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}",
        GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
        // Make a ton of objects for testing purposes.
        object[] tonsOfObjects = new object[50000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            tonsOfObjects[i] = new object();
        // Collect only gen 0 objects.
        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // Print out generation of refToMyCar.
        Console.WriteLine("Generation of refToMyCar is: {0}",
        GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
        // See if tonsOfObjects[9000] is still alive.
        if (tonsOfObjects[9000] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generation of tonsOfObjects[9000] is: {0}",
            GC.GetGeneration(tonsOfObjects[9000]));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("tonsOfObjects[9000] is no longer alive.");
        // Print out how many times a generation has been swept.
        Console.WriteLine("\nGen 0 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(0));
        Console.WriteLine("Gen 1 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Gen 2 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CurrentSpeed { get; set; }
    public string PetName { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
    }

    public Car(string name, int speed)
    {
        PetName = name;
        CurrentSpeed = speed;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} is going {1} MPH", PetName, CurrentSpeed);
    }
}
```

> Here, we have purposely created a very large array of object types (50,000 to be exact) for testing purposes. As you can see from the output that follows, even though this Main() method made only one explicit request for a garbage collection (via the GC.Collect() method), the CLR performed a number of them in the background.

```
***** Fun with System.GC *****
Estimated bytes on heap: 70240
This OS has 3 object generations.
Zippy is going 100 MPH
Generation of refToMyCar is: 0
Generation of refToMyCar is: 1
Generation of tonsOfObjects[9000] is: 1
Gen 0 has been swept 1 times
Gen 1 has been swept 0 times
Gen 2 has been swept 0 times
```

> At this point, I hope you feel more comfortable regarding the details of object lifetime. In the next section, we’ll examine the garbage collection process a bit further by addressing how you can build finalizable objects, as well as disposable objects. Be very aware that the following techniques are typically necessary only if you are building C# classes that maintain internal unmanaged resources.

Why he say he say that CLR performed number of GC in background? Does he just mean that object are promoted from 0 generation to 1st, or that they will be collected when application shutdown or what? AFAIK at this point (before exit Main method) GC ran only once, because we had only one explicit GC, but implicit is impossible, because we are calling methods. So if we call methods of objects, they are definitly non-collected, if we don't - we can't know anything about them inside of Environment. Output also says that 0-generation was collected once, so why does he tell us that `number of GC was performed`?

I love people to write something strange and inevident, but after says `it's obvious, that` or `absolutely clear, that` etc.

okay, i'm increasing array size, but now output is:

```
***** Fun with System.GC *****
Estimated bytes on heap: 37748
This OS has 3 object generations.

Zippy is going 100 MPH

Generation of refToMyCar is: 0
Generation of refToMyCar is: 0
Generation of tonsOfObjects[9000] is: 0

Gen 0 has been swept 1 times
Gen 1 has been swept 1 times
Gen 2 has been swept 1 times
```

code:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***** Fun with System.GC *****");
        // Print out estimated number of bytes on heap.
        Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}",
        GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        // MaxGeneration is zero based.
        Console.WriteLine("This OS has {0} object generations.\n",
        (GC.MaxGeneration + 1));
        Car refToMyCar = new Car("Zippy", 100);
        Console.WriteLine(refToMyCar.ToString());
        // Print out generation of refToMyCar.
        Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}",
        GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
        // Make a ton of objects for testing purposes.
        object[] tonsOfObjects = new object[5000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            tonsOfObjects[i] = new object();
        // Collect only gen 0 objects.
        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // Print out generation of refToMyCar.
        Console.WriteLine("Generation of refToMyCar is: {0}",
        GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
        // See if tonsOfObjects[9000] is still alive.
        if (tonsOfObjects[9000] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generation of tonsOfObjects[9000] is: {0}",
            GC.GetGeneration(tonsOfObjects[9000]));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("tonsOfObjects[9000] is no longer alive.");
        // Print out how many times a generation has been swept.
        Console.WriteLine("\nGen 0 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(0));
        Console.WriteLine("Gen 1 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Gen 2 has been swept {0} times",
        GC.CollectionCount(2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

how is it possible? We had a GC, but object wasn't promoted into 1st generation.

Answer (score 1):

You've only created a pound worth of objects.  Did you take a shortcut on the original code?  Some evidence that you did on the Car class.

To create a ton worth of objects, you'll need to create at least 2 megabytes worth of them to trigger a gen#0 collection.  Arbitrarily change 50000 to 500000 to make enough of them.  Experiment with different values to see what effect that has on the displayed numbers.

Comment: Car class may differ, but output is also provided from original source, so he says that this output contains all required info about.
Now Car class is original (modified)

Comment: Well, he's wrong.  As is obvious from the results.  Do experiment, please, it is incredibly easy to recreate the observation.

Comment: I did what you said, but now output is weirder than before o_O